# Shortest expression for {0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4}

Tags: math, arithmetic, date, atomic-code-golf

Given list of integers `{0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4}`.
For those who interested these numbers are used in weekday calculation.

Weekday = `(m[n] + d + y + y>>2 + y/400 - y/100) % 7;`, where `m[n]` - expression I'm searching, `d` - day of month, `y` - `year - (month <= 2)`.

Construct expression consisting of arithmetic, logic and bitwise operators, which will output for positive integer `n` integer `m` so that `m % 7` equals n-th number in the list.

Branches, ternary operators, table lookups and pointers are not allowed.

**Score:**
1 - for `| & ^ ~ >> <<` operators
1.1 - for `+ - < > <= >= == != ! && ||` operators
1.2 - for `*` operator
1.4 - for `/ %` operators

Answer with lowest score wins.

Personally I have found:

> `(41*n)>>4+((n+61)>>4)<<2` with score 6.4.
>  I thought this will be hard to find so provided own expression to start with.

Comment: I guess array dereferencing (and the kin) isn't allowed either?

Comment: Oh, yes of course, I have edited the question.

Comment: The question would be greatly improved by some motivation. Where do those numbers come from?

Comment: `table lookups` Interesting phrasing I suppose...

Comment: Why not count the %7 in the score? Maybe there's another solution not using %. [Is zero positive](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26705/is-zero-positive-or-negative), negative, both or nothing?

Comment: @ThomasW. %7 needs to be calculated in every case.

Comment: Yes, with the rest of the formula you have given in your updated question, this is clear now. Thanks.

Comment: @m.buettner Thank you for comment. It's my first question, I thought that own example will be good. Next time I won't steal fun)

Comment: What language is the expression supposed to be in? From the examples, I'm assuming C or some C-like language with similar operator syntax (such as C++ or Java), but it would be nice if you could include this information in the challenge (and tag it with the appropriate [language tag](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/907)).

Comment: I want to be it in C. However any language is ok if used operators which are in C language.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## 2 <strike>2.2</strike>

I love arbitrary precision arithmetic.

```
0x4126030156610>>(n<<2)
```

Or, if you don't like hex,

```
1146104239711760>>(n<<2)
```

Test:

```
print([(0x4126030156610>>(n<<2))%7 for n in range(1,13)])
[0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Could you perhaps make a lookup table with `4*n` instead, and save 0.2 points by writing it as `n<<2`?

Comment: @xnor Absolutely! Just to to switch from octal to hexadecimal. Just as sec.

Comment: Cool. I'm pretty convinced nothing can do better because it would require using only one operation, and they all seem to have too much structure mod `7`. My best candidate of integer floor division `const/n` runs into a contradiction with `n=4` and `n=8`.

Comment: @xnor Another close one is `const%n` which could satisfy everything except n=1,2 and 3.

Comment: I was gonna do the same thing, but you beat me to it...

Comment: No way to beat this I think) Btw, how small expression with 32-bit integers is possible?

Comment: @user2992539 I don't know what's optimal under your precise rules, but check out Mike Keith's solution here: http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/zel-like.htm#Keith

Comment: Rechoosen as accepted because first one with smallest score.

Answer (score 33):

### 2.0

```
(127004 >> i) ^ 60233
```

or (score 2.2) :

```
(i * 3246) ^ 130159
```

All found with brute force :-)

Comment: Since this has the same score as isaacg's answer, but doesn't uses 64-bit integers, I'm choosing this as accepted answer. Thank you for answer!

Comment: @user2992539 While it's nice that this answer uses 32-bit integers, you didn't specify this criterion in your challenge, which makes isaacg's answer perfectly valid. Therefore, the two answers tie and I think it's only fair to accept the *first* one that got this score. (Kudos to Super Chafouin, though, +1!)

Comment: @m.buettner I have to agree with you. Next time, I will be more careful with description and answer selection.

Comment: For others to learn, could you elaborate on how you did the brute force calculation?

Comment: @Thomas I just made a double `for` loop, testing all the values p, q for the formula `(p >> i) ^ q`, then went to take a coffee, and 10 mn after came to read the results.

Comment: @SuperChafouin: ok, thanks. So you already had a clear pattern in mind and didn't brute force all operators as well.

Answer (score 8):

### 35.3

I suspect this may be the least efficient method to create the list:

```
1.7801122128869781e+003 * n - 
1.7215267321373362e+003 * n ^ 2 + 
8.3107487075415247e+002 * n ^ 3 - 
2.0576746235987866e+002 * n ^ 4 + 
1.7702949291688071e+001 * n ^ 5 + 
3.7551387326116981e+000 * n ^ 6 - 
1.3296432299817251e+000 * n ^ 7 + 
1.8138635864087030e-001 * n ^ 8 - 
1.3366764519057219e-002 * n ^ 9 + 
5.2402527302299116e-004 * n ^ 10 - 
8.5946393615396631e-006 * n ^ 11 -
7.0418841304671321e+002
```

I just calculated the polynomial regression. I'm tempted to see what other terrible method could be attempted.

Notably, I could save 3.3 points if the result was rounded. At this point, I don't think that matters.

Answer (score 5):

### 3.2

Zero based solution:

```
7 & (37383146136 >> (i*3))
```

One based solution:

```
7 & (299065169088 >> (i*3))
```

I initially thought that the `%7` operation would be counted as well and `%` being an expensive operation here, I tried to solve it without it.

I came to a result of 3.2 like this:

```
// Construction of the number
// Use 3 bits per entry and shift to correct place
long c = 0;
int[] nums = {0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4};
for (int i = nums.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    c <<= 3;
    c += nums[i];
}
// c = 37383146136

// Actual challenge
for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
{
    Console.Write("{0} ",7 & 37383146136 >> i*3);
}
```

I'd be interested in optimizations using this approach (without `%`). Thanks.

Comment: This is cool, maybe this will help me some day) How do you think, maybe I should create separate question for whole formula minimization?

Comment: How about `(0426415305230 >> (i*3)) & 7`? You can see the output digits in reverse order.

Comment: @CJDennis: I think there are no octal numbers in C#.

Comment: I thought it was just C? I can't see any other reference to C#.

Answer (score 0):

## Python (3)

Since there are quite a few of these questions these days, I decided to make a program to automatically solve them in 3 (or 2) tokens. Here's the result for this challenge:

```
G:\Users\Synthetica\Anaconda\python.exe "C:/Users/Synthetica/PycharmProjects/PCCG/Atomic golfer.py"
Input sequence: 0 3 2 5 0 3 5 1 4 6 2 4
f = lambda n: (72997619651120 >> (n << 2)) & 15
f = lambda n: (0x426415305230L >> (n << 2)) & 15
f = lambda n: (0b10000100110010000010101001100000101001000110000 >> (n << 2)) & 15

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Proof that this works:

```
f = lambda n: (72997619651120 >> (n << 2)) & 15

for i in range(12):
   print i, f(i)
 
0 0
1 3
2 2
3 5
4 0
5 3
6 5
7 1
8 4
9 6
10 2
11 4
```

Comment: How does your solver consider the cost of operands?

Comment: @ThomasW. It doesn't, it'll always use a right shift, possibly a left shift (if the values aren't 1 bit) and an `&`.